# How to clear all system versioned tables in one query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables, sp-msforeachtable

I have a query which allows me to delete all rows and reset all indentity columns of all of my tables without breaking any foreign key references. This query works great for normal SQL Server tables:

```sql
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?';
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'', RESEED, 0)';
```

The problem is, that now that I'm using system versioned temporal tables, the previous query doesn't work anymore. My versioned tables are all named `tbl_Foo` and every history table is in the format `tbl_Foo_history`.

I tried using something like this:

```sql
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)';

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?';
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'', RESEED, 0)';

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = ''?''_history))';
```

but it gives the error:

> ```
> SYSTEM_VERSIONING is not turned ON for table 'FOO.dbo.tbl_Foo_history'.
> ```

because the `sp_MSForEachTable` obviously gets really messed up when trying to remove versioning from a history table.

How should I do this without specifying the queries individually for every single table?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way around it using `MSForeachTable`, but you can get some ideas from Aaron Bertrand's [article here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Comment: The queries you try to run can't run on *every* table, only the system versioned tables. It's no different than trying to execute `ALTER TABLE ? DROP Column SomeNonExistentColumn'`. You can't use `sp_MSforeachtable` for this, you'll have to write a script that works only on the tables you want

Comment: BTW you can use `TRUNCATE TABLE` to both delete everything *and* reseed IDENTITY. The current `IDENTITY` value is part of the table data, not its schema

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, the `sp_MSForEachTable was just a starting point, since that worked for me previously. I jsut have no idea how to write a script for this...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't use `TRUNCATE`, since it will give the error:         `Cannot truncate table 'dbo.tbl_Foo' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.`

Comment: `sys.tables` has a `temporal_type` column that will tell you if a table is a temporal table/history table (and a `history_table_id` to point to the history table). You can check this in advance and store the results, though you may need to abandon `sp_msforeachtable` anyway and write your own cursor loop, depending. Also, do have a really good think about what it means for your temporal tables to have their contents reset like this! In particular, verify that whatever temporal queries are used don't get confused by you rewriting things like this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This query will only get used in the developement stage when I'm writing a parser which fills the database with data. I don't want to keep all the incorrect test data there after every run of the program.

Comment: If you're testing and won't need the temporal data at all during that test, you may as well turn off versioning for all tables once, drop the history tables, and turn it on for all tables only after you're done with everything. That way you could keep your existing code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes very true, that could be one solution. I'm simply looking for a more elegant one, which can keep the schema of the database as it will be in the final stage. This way I can expreriment with the temporal table queries while still filling the data.

Comment: Then I'd say backup/restore, redeploy from database project, or reset to snapshot are technically all more elegant than manually cleaning out tables. Although that may still be more attractive because it's generally faster than the other solutions (though not as reliable). I'll still mention them for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with just creating the same queries for each of my tables with a Vim macro. It looks ugly, but in practice was very quick to implement:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Foo1 SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Foo2 SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
ALTER TABLE ...

ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Foo1 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Foo2 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE ...

DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_Foo1;
DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_Foo2;
DELETE FROM ...

DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_Foo1_history;
DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_Foo2_history;
DELETE FROM ...

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[tbl_Foo1]', RESEED, 0);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[tbl_Foo2]', RESEED, 0);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ...

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[tbl_Foo1_history]', RESEED, 0);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[tbl_Foo2_history]', RESEED, 0);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ...

ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Foo1 WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Foo2 WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE ...

ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Foo1 SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.tbl_Foo1_history));
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Foo2 SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.tbl_Foo2_history));
ALTER TABLE ...
```